# Doubt in a step in the proof of Fatou's lemma

Tags: measure-theory

I am reading a proof of Fatou's lemma and I don't follow a step. Consider a sequence of non-negative measurable functions on $X$ to $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$. Fatou's lemma states that

$$\int(\lim\inf f_n)\,d\mu\leq\lim\inf\int{}f_n\,d\mu$$

where $\mu$ is a measure on $X$. The proof begins by considering the sequence

$$g_m=\inf\{f_m,f_{m+1},f_{m+2},\ldots\}$$

therefore, if $m\leq{}n$ we have that

$$\int{}g_m\,d\mu\leq\int{}f_n\,d\mu$$

as long as $m\leq{}n$. The next step states that implies

$$\int{}g_m\,d\mu\leq\lim\inf\int{}f_n\,d\mu$$

I don't see this. How does this follow?

Comment: This follows by the definition of $\liminf$. $$\liminf_{n \to \infty} x_n = \sup \{ a : \mbox{ eventually }  x_n \ge a \} $$ What definition do you have?

Answer (score 1):

Informally, because you might chop off the minimum when you pass to a subset.  That is, we have used the fact $$
    F \subset G \implies \inf F \geq \inf G  \text{.}
$$

The expression $\liminf \int f_n \,\mathrm{d}\mu$ asks one to compute "the lower bound of the sequence of successive tails of the sequence".  At some point, that sequence of successive tails is eventually (and then forever after) a subset of $F_m = \{\int f_m, \int f_{m+1}, \dots \}$.  So we subsequently only consider subsets of $F_m$, and their infima can be no less than the infimum of the full set.  I.e.,  $$
    \inf F_m \leq \inf F_{m+1} \leq \inf F_{m+2} \leq \cdots
$$

Comment: but here you assume that in $\int{}g_m\,d\mu$ you can commute the integral and the infimum. Is this so, and if so why?

Comment: @AnarchistBirdsWorshipFungus : Do you agree that $g_m \leq f_n \implies \int g_m \leq \int f_n$?  Then, do you agree that $g_m \leq f_n, g_m \leq f_{n+1}, \dots \implies \int g_m \leq \int f_n, \int g_m \leq \int f_{n+1}, \dots$?